# Flutter get selected value from dropdownmenu from other class

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to get the currently selected value from the dropdown menu in another class of my Flutter web app. As the dropdownValue variable is local, it is not usable outside the scope of its class.
Here is what I tried:

```
class _DPWidgetState extends State < DPWidget > {
String dropdownValue = '1';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton < String > (
        value: dropdownValue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        iconSize: 24,
        elevation: 16,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
        underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        ),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
            });
        },
        items: < String > ['1', '2', '3']
        .map < DropdownMenuItem < String >> ((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem < String > (
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
            );
        }).toList(),
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Is this other class needing acess to selected value parent of this widget?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Yes I want the other class to get the updated value as the user changes the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends where the other class is located in your widget tree. If it is the parent of your DPWidget, I would pass a callback method from the parent class to your widget and use it as onChanged callback. No need to use setState anymore. That way you can use the dropdownValue to alter state in the parent class.

Otherwise I would recommend to use the provider package to alter the state somewhere else in your widget tree. With a provider you can listen to state changes wherever you want and react as you like.

Comment: Can you refer me to any working example of "pass a callback method from the parent class to your widget and use it as onChanged callback"? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

there is different approach depends of your widget tree setup
**1- callback function:**
in case if your widget is directly connected to your statefulWidget
**2- provider packages:**
in case if your widgets aren't directly connected to avoid using lot of callbacks this package  does help you to call change some in this provider and than notify all the widgets who listen to this provider class .

Comment: The other class is not in the widget tree.

Comment: its a widget class ?

Comment: The other classes where I want the selected value of the dropdown looks like this:
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {}

Comment: this might help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-widget-communication
you can fix it with callback function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value from one page to another using navigation try it out.

Comment: Basically, I want a search button whose output will vary based on the selected item in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am telling just pass the selected item to the next page.